# a simple application iOS, trying to learn Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am doing a simple application iOS, trying to learn Swift, but simply gives an error code, and I do not know how to fix it, if someone tells will be grateful.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell: UITableViewCell  = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    // swift:34:24: Cannot assign to 'textLabel' in 'cell' this error is here
    cell.textLabel = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name

    //'UILabel?' does not have a member named 'text' this error is here
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desk

    return cell

}
```

Comment: You should provide more info, such as if it's a compilation or runtime error, the error message, which line, and any other relevant info.

Comment: Ze has commented the errors above the affected lines. It's clear i.m.o

Comment: at least the error type and a mention that it's commented in the code would be helpful and should be included in the question, for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.text
```

You forgot the `.text`

And also, you need to use `?` to safely unwrap the optional `detailTextLabel`:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text
```

Comment: Mind telling me why this got downvoted? O.o

Comment: no idea, you're right about the solution.

Comment: People are just mad or badges hungry, happens me all the time. You asked the question. Upvote